# Prove or disprove that every finite extension of $\text{Frac}\left(\Bbb{F}_{121}[X,Y]/(Y^2-f)\right)$ is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $f\in\Bbb{F}_{121}[X]$ be irreducible, $R=\Bbb{F}_{121}[X,Y]/(Y^2-f)$ and $K=\text{Frac}(R)$.
I know that every finite extension of finite fields is separable, but I couldn't show that $K$ is a finite field. I also tried to show that the Frobenius $F:x\mapsto x^{121}$ is an automorphism of $K$, which would imply $K$ is perfect, but I couldn't show that either.

Comment: The field $K$ is a quadratic extension of  the field of rational functions $F=\Bbb{F}_{121}(X)$. Basically $Y=\sqrt{f}$. So every element of $K$ can be written in the form $a_0(X)+\sqrt{f} a_1(X)$ with $a_0(X),a_1(X)\in F$. From this it should be easy to show that not every element of $K$ is an eleventh power of another element of $K$. This allows inseparable extensions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that makes sense, thank you! Is there a good way to guess which element is not going to be an 11th power?

Comment: Raising to eleventh is additive, so $$\left(a_0(x)+\sqrt f a_1(x)\right)^{11}=a_0(x)^{11}+\sqrt f (f^5 a_1(x)^{11}).$$

Comment: Much more generally, if $L\supset k$ is a finitely generated extension of a perfect field of characteristic $p>0$, and of transcendence degree $n>0$, then $L^{1/p}\supset L$ is purely inseparable, of degree equal to $p^n$. In your case, $p=11$ and $n=1$.

Comment: @Lubin that's a cool result. Do you know where I can find the proof?

Comment: Golly, @14159 , I think you just prove it yourself. Start with a transcendence basis, generating a purely transcendental extension $L_0$ of $k$. Now apply the $p$-th root operation to $L_0$, and see how the result  sits inside $L^{1/p}$.